# After login with simple_token_authentication rails redirects to referer domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have two rails apps on my local machine, app A and app B. App A redirects the visitor to app B with a login token, which it had received previously from app A (simple_token_authentication). The URL looks something like `"/offers/F6MyubLfP5dKcrGLp?project_id=337&user_id=93&user_token=6s3xaoxRLNyJ8VG7wqEF"`. In most cases it works fine. The authentication is successful and the user sees the the correct page in app B.

But sometimes the user will be redirected to app A. I don't no why and where I must start with debugging.

App B's log when it receives the login url and redirects (302 Found) back to App A:

```
Started GET "/offers/F6MyubLfP5dKcrGLp?project_id=337&user_id=93&user_token=6s3xaoxRLNyJ8VG7wqEF" for ::1 at 2020-10-07 10:53:40 +0200
Processing by OffersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"project_id"=>"337", "user_id"=>"93", "user_token"=>"6s3xaoxRLNyJ8VG7wqEF", "id"=>"F6MyubLfP5dKcrGLp"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 92], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:58:in `require_login'
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 93], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:65:in `after_successful_token_authentication'
  User Exists? (0.5ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."wegateam_contact_id" = $1 AND "users"."id" != $2 LIMIT $3  [["wegateam_contact_id", 233], ["id", 92], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:65:in `after_successful_token_authentication'
   (0.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" WHERE "users"."authentication_token" = $1  [["authentication_token", "vDQWLATe_x5_V3AxL7ep"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:65:in `after_successful_token_authentication'
  User Update (0.6ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "authentication_token" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "users"."id" = $3  [["authentication_token", "vDQWLATe_x5_V3AxL7ep"], ["updated_at", "2020-10-07 08:53:40.483669"], ["id", 92]]
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:65:in `after_successful_token_authentication'
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:65:in `after_successful_token_authentication'
Redirected to http://localhost:5000/
Completed 302 Found in 98ms (ActiveRecord: 3.1ms | Allocations: 10039)
```

Authentication seems to be successful, because simple_token_authentication's method `after_successful_token_authentication` is executed.

```
# overwrite simple_token_authentication hook: token will only be valid for one login
  def after_successful_token_authentication
    current_user.update(authentication_token: nil)
    # Token will renewed when saving
  end
```

When it works as expected http response looks like this:

[image]

When the unwished redirect will be executed, it looks like this:

[image]

When I manually copy and paste the url after the unwished redirect, the login works fine.

It seems to be, that the problem occurs only when the App B user was created shortly before.

What I tried:

- Because app B's user was created shortly before (and sends the authentication token to app A) I thought maybe devise and simple_token_authentication are not ready with their actions and that results in the redirect. So I made a timeout of 10 seconds in app A before it sends the user to the login URL of app B. But same result.

I would even appreciate suggestions where I could start searching for solutions of that problem.

UPDATE: The application_controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :store_user_location!, if: :storable_location?
  before_action :require_login

  include Pundit

  # Pundit: Ensure, that authorize has been called
  # after_action :verify_authorized
  # after_action :verify_policy_scoped

  # Catch Pundit::NotAuthorizedError
  rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, with: :user_not_authorized

  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception, prepend: true

  # For simple_token_authentication (Bei Anforderung magic login kann der user nicht eingeloggt sein. In diesem Fall nicht
  # authentifizieren)
  acts_as_token_authentication_handler_for User, except: :request_magic_login

  def user_not_authorized
    flash[:error] = "Du hast keine ausreichende Berechtigung diese Seite zu öffnen."
    redirect_to(request.referrer || root_path)
  end

  # Devise Methode überschreiben, um nach Login zu der Seite weiterzuleiten, die der User egentlich aufrufen wollte,
  # bevor er auf die Login Seite geleitet wurde.
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    stored_location_for(resource_or_scope) || super
  end

  private

  def redirect_to_project_or_select_page(user)
    if user.contact.projects.size != 1
      redirect_to user_projects_path(user)
    else
      redirect_to project_path(user.contact.projects.first.id)
    end
  end

  # Its important that the location is NOT stored if:
  # - The request method is not GET (non idempotent)
  # - The request is handled by a Devise controller such as Devise::SessionsController as that could cause an
  #    infinite redirect loop.
  # - The request is an Ajax request as this can lead to very unexpected behaviour.
  # https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update
  def storable_location?
    request.get? && is_navigational_format? && !devise_controller? && !request.xhr?
  end

  def store_user_location!
    # :user is the scope we are authenticating
    store_location_for(:user, request.fullpath)
  end

  def require_login
    if !current_user && !devise_controller? && (!request.params[:user_id] || !request.params[:user_token])
      redirect_to new_user_session_path
    end
  end

  # simple_token_authentication hook überschreiben: token soll nur für einen Login gelten
  def after_successful_token_authentication
    current_user.update(authentication_token: nil)
    # Wird beim speichern dann neu gesetzt
  end
end
```

Comment: You're doing multiple queries to find the same user. Those could potentially be optimised but I think the issue is also there somewhere. Can you share what each user query is used for?

Comment: @TomDunning: The first "User Load" is initialized by "require_login" in application_controller. It checks for the most pages if the user must be logged in. It then redirects to the logged in page if necessary. The next three operations on the user came from this line: `current_user.update(authentication_token: nil)` in `simple_token_authentication`'s `after_successful_token_authentication`. It assures that the user becomes a new login token if the old one is used. I don't now why this line leads to three DB operations.

Comment: @TomDunning: I forgot to say, require_login does not redirect to login page when a token is present in the url (!request.params[:user_token])

Comment: So you're using this standard hook: https://github.com/gonzalo-bulnes/simple_token_authentication#hooks . Have you checked that all the servers which might send this request are allowed? If it's a random error it could be that the CSRF tokens don't line up for one of your servers. If it's not that I'd need to see some more code. Ideally the application_controller and what fallback option you've sent. I'd also check where current_user is set and ensure there's no race condition where clearing that token suddenly makes them invalid. Finally I'd which page they would go to on success.

Comment: @TomDunning All servers allowed? I think so, because when I try the same setup a second time with that user, it works (besides the the server is the same for both apps, localhost). CSRF token not lined up? I don't think so, because in application_controller `protect_from_forgery with: :exception, prepend: true` would have raised an exception. Clearing that token suddenly makes them invalid? The second attempt with the same token works. I have added the application_controller to my question.

Comment: Looking at your controller I would suspect Pundit returning a failure is the most likely thing to cause the issue as it is the only think calling `redirect_to(request.referrer || root_path)`. I would add a few `Rails.logger.info` lines to that function and a few others. We need to eliminate some options and pinpoint what the last function to execute is before the redirect. (Your current logging only shows functions which involve a DB query).